# React-router-dom page navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Trying on simple navigation with `react-router-dom`. Managed to have it works with `this.props.history.push('/pathName');` However, I have doubts about my understanding and implementation, appreciate your 2 cents on correcting my mistakes.

Am I in the right direction?

**My use case scenario:**

Firstly, I have 3 pages with a common component `<Navbar>` implemented on top of each page. `Navbar` consists of 2 buttons Page A and Page B. User should be navigated to either screen when the respective button is clicked.

1. Homepage
2. Page A
3. Page B

**My Implementation:**

Homepage.js - (Besides the class name is different, both Page A and B has the same implementation)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import Navbar from '../common/navbar';

class Homepage extends React.Component{  

 callBackFromNavBar = (value) => {
    NavigationHelper.historyPush(this.props, value);
  }

  render(){

    return (
      <div>
          <Navbar callback={this.callBackFromNavBar}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Homepage;
```

NavigationHelper.js

```
export const historyPush = (props,value) => {
    console.log('helper calling');
    switch(value){
        case 'PageA':
            props.history.push('/PageA');
            break;
        case 'PageB':
            props.history.push('/PageB');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Navbar - Following shows how the **value** is being pass back to parent

```
<Button variant="contained" onClick={ () => {
            props.callback('PageA');
          } }>Page A</Button>
```

**Learning source:**

1. https://dev.to/projectescape/programmatic-navigation-in-react-3p1l

**Link to Sandbox**

https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-router-dom-navigation-4tpzs?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: can you share codesandbox link

Comment: tried doing it on codesandbox, didnt manage to make it work. Maybe you can point out which part is unclear to you?

Comment: @vinayakshahdeo I have updated the question with Sandbox link.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this to simplify things

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import PageA from './'
import PageB from './'

function App() {
  return (
   <Router>
     <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/pageA" component={PageA} />
          <Route exact path="/pageB" component={PageB} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

And then in your Navbar component just setup the `<Link>` to each of those pages, here i have setup the routes in the App.js file however i have seen people just use a dedicated component for routing but find what works best for you

Comment: Hello @ShrewdStyle, yes `<Link>` will work however Im using some components to show the button instead `<Link>`. Therefore I need to do it programmatically, in future there may be param passing as well. My bad, should hv mentioned in the question before.